# ¿Cómo poner Android Studio en español?

Tags: android, android-studio, idioma

¿Cómo cambio el idioma del IDE a español?

Desconozco si hay una nueva versión, actualización o parche. Estoy usando Android Studio Giraffe 2022.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

Según [esta publicación](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2021/07/language-packs-public-release/), además de Inglés, puedes cambiar el idioma del IDE a Chino, Japonés y Coreano oficialmente mediante plugins. No parece que hayan agregado otro idioma desde entonces.

Sin embargo, alguien creó [un plugin](https://github.com/macastro/SpanishLanguagePack-JetBrains) para IntelliJ IDEA que puedes usar aunque no esté completamente traducido. Puedes encontrar la versión correspondiente [aquí](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/android-studio-releases-list.html). Yo probé con la versión 223 del plugin en Android Studio 2022.3.1 y me funcionó.

El procedimiento para instalarlo es el siguiente:

- Ir a **Plugins**.
- Hacer clic en el ícono del engranaje ⚙️.
- Hacer clic en **Install plugin from disk...**.
- Buscar y seleccionar el archivo del plugin.
- Confirmar y reiniciar el IDE.

Puedes consultar [la documentación](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-plugins.html#install_plugin_from_disk) para más información.

Answer (score 0):

Hasta el día de hoy enero 2024 **no existe una opción en la configuración de Android Studio o Intellij Idea para cambiar la IDE a idioma español**.

La única opción es usar un plugin, que en este caso solo existe uno hasta el día de hoy y es el mencionado en la respuesta de Mateo

Debes descargar el .jar desde la página:
https://github.com/macastro/SpanishLanguagePack-JetBrains

e instalar el plugin desde el disco, cargando el .jar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para obtener una traducción del IDE en idioma español.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

si extraes este archivo puedes modificar el archivo llamado PropertiesBundle.properties, puedes cambiar los textos a idioma español:

```
duplicate.property.key.error.message=Duplicate property key
rename.prefix.based.property.key.error.message=Could not rename property key ''{1}'' based on prefix ''{0}'' by name ''{2}'', change prefix first
properties.files.file.type.description=Properties
remove.property.intention.text=Remove property
rename.bundle.enter.new.resource.bundle.base.name.prompt.text=Enter new resource bundle base name
rename.bundle.enter.new.resource.bundle.section.name.prompt.text=Enter new resource bundle section name
rename.resource.bundle.dialog.title=Rename Resource Bundle
rename.resource.bundle.section.dialog.title=Rename Resource Bundle Section
properties.files.inspection.group.display.name=Properties Files
unused.property.inspection.display.name=Unused Property
searching.for.property.key.progress.text=Searching for {0}
unused.property.problem.descriptor.name=Unused property
remove.property.quick.fix.name=Remove Property
no.property.selected.panel.label=<html><body><center>Please select property name on the left to edit its values</body></html>
```

Cabe aclarar que no todos los textos se encuentran aquí.